# Unable to create new remote session with latest selenium server and geckodriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using the latest selenium standalone version as of version 3.4 and the newest geckodriver as of version v0.16.1. I am unable to start a new remote session.

I always get:

```
Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@6b994b98}, platform=ANY, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@6b994b98}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@6b994b98}, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@6b994b98}]
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: '71001A2', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.0-49-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Are these two softwares not compatible?

I am using the latest firefox (53.0.2 (64-Bit)) on ubuntu linux.

I start selenium standalone like this:

`sudo java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/Selenium/webdrivers/geckodrive‌​r selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar`

**UPDATE**: Everything works again after restart of the system.

Comment: Need some more info: 1. Are you starting the Hub & Node with default settings? 2. If not, share the json here. 3. What worked for you? Show code. Thanks

Comment: I do not run hub and nodes. It is just a normal selenium standalone server, without selenium grid. The code is not the problem, since it works with older versions.

Comment: A lot have changed in Selenium 3.x What is your exact Testing step? Can you share your work with us please?

Comment: I am using custom code so it would not help. I am basically just opening the github login page, fetching username and password field and send data into it, then i submit.

Comment: That's pretty simple. What bindings are you using for Selenium?

Comment: I start selenium standalone like this `sudo java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/Selenium/webdrivers/geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar`

Comment: But that is a part of Grid configuration while you mentioned you want to execute in normal scenario.

Comment: You are yet to specify your Selenium binding

Comment: No, this is not the grid configuration. The grid configuration looks way different.

Comment: Today everything just works fine. Maybe my computer just needed a restart?

Comment: Great news !!! Had you had been updated me with your code I would have suggested that too :)

Comment: It had nothing to to with my code though since i did not changed it, I think the webserver or my computer just needed a restart.

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to do a `java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/Selenium/webdrivers/geckodrive‌​r selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar` on your linux box until & unless you want to start it as a Selenium Grid Server.

Comment: @Dev, I start it as a normal selenium standalone server. How else should I start it?

Comment: While working with `Selenium 3.4.0` with `geckodriver v0.16.1` & `Mozilla Firefox 53.x` on my Windows 8 box I simply specify the absolute path of the geckodriver in your code and start my Testcase execution as follows: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckoedriver.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
driver.get("https:/www.google.com/");

Comment: Where as when I need to start the Selenium grid as a HUB, I simply start it from Command-Line with the following command: `java -jar C:\your_location\selenium-server-standalone\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub`

Comment: You don't need to start it as a hub if you only have one node. In this case just start it like I did.

Comment: Well, honestly once I write a piece of automation code, I execute it on several nodes with different OS box, different browsers & different versions of that browser :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Firefox 53.0.2 and geckodriver v0.16.1 and managed to run tests on a remote Windows VM as follows -
I've got my geckodriver.exe in the same path on both machines (just to be safe, but should work as long as you specify the correct path when starting the node off on the remote VM)

In my test, I initialise the driver with his code:

```
public class SeleniumGrid_ParallelTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private String geckoPath = "C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe";
    private String nodeURL;

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() throws MalformedURLException {
    //  FOR FF 53.0.2
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoPath);
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
    nodeURL = "http://192.168.75.128:5555/wd/hub"; // Remote VM IP address and port
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
    caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), caps);

//    then the rest of the test as normal
```

On my hub, I start it with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub
```

On my remote VM, I start the node off from the command prompt with:

```
cd C:\Selenium
java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://<hub name or IP>:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=firefox,version=58.0.3029.110,maxInstances=2,platform=WINDOWS
```

Run the test from my hub machine (my laptop) through Eclipse and switch to the remote VM. Assuming you've got Firefox installed, the test will run on the remote VM OK, with the logs being created on your PC as normal.